# DynamicDataDisplay chart tools, programmatically adding (pannable) controls to a chart (using ViewportHostPanel)

Tags: charts, controls, viewport, dynamic-data-display

Dynamic Data Display is a fantastic library that so far has been very useful for me. Thanks go to Mikhail Brinchuk for developing the library.

This posting gives a great tip for adding controls to DynamicDataDisplay charts using xaml that pan and zoom with the chart content: https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/74886

This allows the placement of an image, text, or whatever, on the chart that moves with the chart axes. This is all done in xaml.

How do I add these in the cs code such that I can add controls to the chart (markers, images and such) at run-time? I'm trying to plot some GPS data in one chart using Google maps as the source images. In another chart I'd like to add controls that pan with the data. The above link does this, but I am not able to add it at run-time, nor specify the position in my chart data.

Comment: Really?  It's called D3?  'cause there's another library called [d3](d3js.org) which is what your tag "d3.js" refers to.  Note the JS.  Weird that Microsoft is calling a data display library "D3".  I'm mosdef confused.

Comment: whoops, you're right, corrections to follow..